# Unable to fetch a link from an email in the gmail when run on jenkins but works and fetches desired result locally (in the WATIR framework using ruby)

Tags: ruby

The following code when run on jenkins throws the error as 'The set password url is
invalid argument(Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.88) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)
Backtrace: Ordinal0 [0x00A67413+2389011]"

**STEP FILE:**

```
When(/^the user clicks on activate online account link$/) do

  on(CheckoutPage) do |page|

    #sleep for 30 seconds for the email to be received

    sleep 30

    p @set_password_link = page.get_password_token

    puts "The set password url is #{@set_password_link}"

    page.navigate_to(@set_password_link)

  end

end
```

**Code FILE:**

```
def get_password_token

  begin

    retries ||= 0

    Gmail.new("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx") do |gmail|

      email = gmail.inbox.emails(:from => 'orders@cottonon.com', :subject => 'Activate your online account').last

      html = email.html_part.body.to_s

      urls = URI.extract(html, %w(https))

      return urls[1]

    end

  rescue

    retry if (retries += 1) < $code_retry

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be number of things, maybe you just need URI.parse(urls[1]) or fetched url is invalid

also it seems like your gmail code always fetches last mail, which can return wrong one if email is still not received

Here is a gmail_check method that should be more resistant to mail content and time received

```rb
def gmail_check(url_part, receiver, timeout = 30)       
    time = (Time.now-5.minutes).to_i            
    Gmail.connect("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx") do |gmail|       
        puts("Reading emails to: #{receiver}")
        while (timeout > 0)
            gmail.inbox.find(:gm => "\"after:#{time}\"").each do |mail| 
                if mail.message.to.first == receiver
                    content = mail.multipart? ? mail.html_part.decoded : mail.message.decoded
                    Nokogiri::HTML(content).css("a").each do |a|
                        href = a.attributes["href"].to_s
                        return href if href.include?(url_part)
                    end
                end
            end
            puts("Waiting 5 seconds before reading mail again.")            
            timeout = timeout - 5
            sleep 5
        end
    end
end
```

but you should be able to easily debug the problem by ssh-ing into jenkins machine,

1. type `irb`
2. type `require gmail`
3. paste your code there
4. check the url

good luck :)

Comment: It is exactly failing to connect at this point on Jenkins slave box.... Gmail.connect("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx") do |gmail|
It does not go furthur than this in the code.

Comment: try only connecting without block: `gmailing = Gmail.connect("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx")`

then inspect the object: `gmailing.inspect`

does it say `#<Gmail::Client0x55f83f6e9230 ("xxxxxxx@gmail.com") disconnected>`

if so, your app password is incorrect; go to Gmail => Manage your Google Account => Security => Signing int to Google => Apps passwords => Generate app password"